# Как использовать Service Reference(ссылку на сервис) в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, веб-служба

Visual Studio 2013 for Web.
Имеется солюшн, содержащий 2 проекта(Client и Service).
В Client находится index.html, JavaScript и CSS файлы.
В Service находится веб-сервис WebService.asmx, dbml и несколько классов.

При запуске стартуют оба проекта, в последовательности Service(порт 53803) -> Client(порт 53822).
Из-за разных адресов у запущенных проектов, обращение к веб-сервису с клиента через ajax возвращает ошибку 404. Прописывать ссылку на веб-сервис "в лоб" не вариант, потому что неизвестно, какой порт будет присвоен проекту при старте на другой машине(задание является тестовым и будет отправляться на проверку).

Каким образом можно передать ссылку на этот веб сервис в клиент?
Добавил ссылку на него в Service Reference на клиенте, но что делать дальше и как её использовать при вызове сервиса через JS ума не приложу.

Условие, что клиент строго *.html и в разных проектах с сервисом.

P.S. Если index.html положить в проект с веб-сервисом, то всё работает.